# crc24 from c to python

Tags: python, c, translation, port

can someone please translate this code to python? i have tried and tried again, but have not managed it:

```
  #define CRC24_INIT 0xB704CEL
  #define CRC24_POLY 0x1864CFBL

  typedef long crc24;
  crc24 crc_octets(unsigned char *octets, size_t len)
  {
      crc24 crc = CRC24_INIT;
      int i;
      while (len--) {
          crc ^= (*octets++) << 16;
          for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
              crc <<= 1;
              if (crc & 0x1000000)
                  crc ^= CRC24_POLY;
          }
      }
      return crc & 0xFFFFFFL;
  }
```

i have the rotate left function (`ROL24(value,bits_to_rotate_by)`), which i know works since i got it from a source code of a reputable programmer, but i dont get the `*` and `++` on octet. i only sort of understand how `++` works in c++, and i dont know what `*` is at all

my code is:

```
def crc24(octets, length):# now octects is a binary string
 INIT = 0xB704CE
 POLY = 0x1864CFB
 crc = INIT
 index = 0
 while length:
  crc ^= (int(octets[index], 2) << 16)
  index += 1
  for i in xrange(8):
   crc = ROL(crc, 1)
   if crc & 0x1000000:
    crc ^= POLY
  length -= 1
 return crc & 0xFFFFFF
```

Comment: What was the problem with your Python version? Could you post your attempt in Python and maybe someone here will be able to correct your mistakes instead of writing everything from scratch.

Comment: here. Im willing to guess that the `octet[index]` is my main problem

Comment: One problem is that you use `int(octets[index], 2)` which looks at the string at position index and then tries to interpret it as a binary _digit_ (bit) instead of an octet (byte). Use `ord(octets[index])` instead. Your current code should raise an exception. It would be helpful if you always tell what exceptions your code raises instead of just saying that there is a problem in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Yes, there is no 'length' parameter here. We don't need it in Python.
def crc24(octets):
    INIT = 0xB704CE
    POLY = 0x1864CFB
    crc = INIT
    for octet in octets: # this is what the '*octets++' logic is effectively
    # accomplishing in the C code.
        crc ^= (octet << 16)
        # Throw that ROL function away, because the C code **doesn't** actually
        # rotate left; it shifts left. It happens to throw away any bits that are
        # shifted past the 32nd position, but that doesn't actulaly matter for
        # the correctness of the algorithm, because those bits can never "come back"
        # and we will mask off everything but the bottom 24 at the end anyway.
        for i in xrange(8):
            crc <<= 1
            if crc & 0x1000000: crc ^= POLY
    return crc & 0xFFFFFF
```

Comment: oohhhhh.... thanks! i cant believe i mistook the `<<` for rotate instead of simply shift. thank you so much for doing this. i would check this as the answer, but im not a member yet

Comment: it turns out its not quite right, but i'll live with it for now, since it is much more logically written than my version

Comment: @biiiiiaw: How is it not quite right? If you notice a problem, and even take the time to write about it, you might as well tell what the actual problem is. Even if can "live with it", it might be useful for someone else to know.

Comment: @pafcu works perfect for me, just manually verified an OpenPGP packet

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python but `unsigned char *octets` is a pointer (you can think of it as an array of size len).

`*octets` returns the first element.

the `++` moves the point to the next element.

so the line `crc ^= (*octets++) << 16;`

is basically the same as this pseudo code (index is set to 0 once.)

```
(global var index = 0)

temp = octets[index] shift left 16 bits
crc = crc bitwise xor temp
index = index + 1
```